# Using imagejpeg() function to save image file

Tags: php

I am trying to upload the picture into two different directories and I would like to use the `imagejpeg()` function to put the picture in one of the directories. The two directories are called `uploads` and `resized`.

Here is my code to accomplish this:

```
$tmp_name = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    imagejpeg($tmp_name,"resized/newimage.jpg");

    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
}
```

However, I keep getting the error `imagejpeg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in /home/sites/aejhyun.com/public_html/Syrian Project/upload.php on line 41`. I also did some research by looking here http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php. However, I could not figure this problem out. Could anybody help?

Comment: Can you give and your html ?

Comment: Which part of _imagejpeg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given_ did you not understand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are setting string as $tmp_name and not an Image Resource itself , the function wants actual Image and not location or name of it , if you want to resize it , first you have to open it as Image then do whatever you want and finally save,

so , this is string

```
$tmp_name = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];
```

after you move it to **$target_file** you can open it as image

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($target_file);
```

now you have Image itself and not just a file name and you can save it with **imagejpeg**

```
imagejpeg($image,"resized/newimage.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
$url = 'my_img_url.jpeg';
$binary = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($url));
imageJpeg($binary, "myimage.jpg", 100);
```